# 10G Ethernet IEEE: sfp+ for 10gbase T

Tags: ethernet

can someone tell me for 10G Ethernet:

When I use PHY -> SFP+-> RJ45 CAT 5 or 6

And the VSC PHY e.g. doesn't support 10GBaseT.

**Does the SFP+ Pluggable use internally PAM 16 encoding ?**

Can someone show me that only the SFP+ is responsible for PAM-16?
Or is the PHY responsible for this encoding?

55.Physical Coding Sublayer (PCS), Physical Medium Attachment (PMA)
sublayer and baseband medium, type 10GBASE-T

[image: IEEE PAM16]
http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/VPPD-01080.pdf

> A copper SFP is not like a fiber optic SFP. It performs more involved
> data conversions, that is, from 8b /10b to 5PAM and vice-versa,
> whereas a fiber optic SFP performs an electrical to optical signal
> conversion and vice-versa.

**update:**  I will use my phy which doesnt support PAM16 10GBASE T and use SFP+ RJ45 and try to send/receive data

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but if your SFP module doesn't support 10GBaseT then it won't use 10GBaseT. Instead it'll use whatever it supports.

Comment: What is a "VSC" PHY?

Comment: hey first question: the SFP pluggable converts from PHY to the lane. And it is extra for this issue: https://www.amazon.de/Transceiver-10GBase-T-Kompatibel-SFP-10G-T-S-UF-RJ45-10G/dp/B01M8O3MAL?th=1  second question:  they really call them vsc phys: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/AN3576-Software-for-VSC-PHYs-00003576A.pdf

Comment: I found this for a older SFP of microchip. It shows some SFP copper internals... I will check it out.. http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/VPPD-01080.pdf

Comment: Could you try to explain your question more clearly? You have VSC series SFP+ module and want to know something about it. That is all I could understand

Comment: normally the VSC-PHY endodes the data with line encoding so that the SFP+ can send the data securely. This encoding will translate normal data into a bit pattern that is stable when send really fast.  So the SFP+ sends this stable bit pattern. The VSC-PHY needs to know the encoding type.  If it should be sent via optical fiber, the VSC-PHY encodes it with 64B/66B. If it should be sent on a pcb 8B/10B is used. The SFP+tx will just stupidly use the data from the PHY and send it through the medium.  Can the SFP+ also encode data?

Comment: The SFP module handles encoding the data for the transmission medium. For example, for a fiber module there is a laser for optical transmission while a copper one includes hardware for splitting the serial signal into 4 slower twisted pair signals. Each SFP transmitter only supports one thing so it already knows what it supports.

Comment: You say: "For example, for a fiber module there is a laser for optical transmission while a copper one includes hardware for splitting the serial signal into 4 slower twisted pair signals. " But the real data encoding, where does it happen? I mean like 64B/66B ? Is it in the PHY or in SFP? I know that SFP has e.g. laser. But has it also 64B/66B or PAM-16 encoding?